# Zend_Gdata - Create entry with 'Search Description' field

Tags: php, blogger

I'm creating php application for Blogger - I'll be adding posts automatically from my script

Here is the function:

```
function createPublishedPost($title='Hello, world!', $content='I am blogging on the internet.')
{
  global $blogID, $gdClient;
  $uri = 'http://www.blogger.com/feeds/' . $blogID . '/posts/default';
  $entry = $gdClient->newEntry();
  $entry->title = $gdClient->newTitle($title);
  $entry->content = $gdClient->newContent($content);
  $entry->content->setType('text');
  //$entry->label = $gdClient->newLabel("sadasff,dsfsdg,gd,g");

  // here adding labels - categories 
  $labels = $entry->getCategory();
  $newLabel = $gdClient->newCategory('testlabel2', 'http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#');
  $labels[] = $newLabel; // Append the new label to the list of labels. 
  $entry->setCategory($labels);

  $createdPost = $gdClient->insertEntry($entry, $uri);
  $idText = split('-', $createdPost->id->text);
  $newPostID = $idText[2];

  return $newPostID;
}
```

This works fine, but I want to include also 'Search Description' field for blogger post.
I've tried something like this:

```
  $entry->description = $gdClient->newDescription("some search terms here");
```

but unfortunately this does not work.

If anyone has ever had the same problem, help will be much appreciated

Comment: sorry I'd post this to programmers, can you transfer this?... :/

Comment: Can you expand on "does not work"? Bug reports usually comprise of a description of what was expected, and what actually happened, including error messages and any other pertinent details.

Comment: I think it's not even built in this app but can't figure out how to add :/

Comment: I'm not fully clear what you need. You say you "want to include also 'Search Description' field for blogger post". I initially though this would be a form on your site that allows you to search through blog posts, but then the above code would be an inappropriate place to put it. Maybe, then, you mean that you wish to send a field to the `insertEntry` call _containing_ keywords, so that it gets recorded on the blogger.com side?

Comment: If the latter, then I'd start by looking at the docs for the class for `$gdClient` - what does it allow? Do Blogger posts allow arbitrary fields to be attached? Is there an example on a Blogger devs portal somewhere, maybe?

Comment: you are right, I'm asking this question here because I've not found anything about it anywhere else :/

Comment: Alright, well I have given you some leads to try. Also, make sure you are using an autocompleting IDE, so you can explore the instance you have.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I think it does not have that functionality unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion : Maybe you can try to use the meta **description**.